# AppConfig.java return bean with private constructor?

Tags: java, spring, spring-ioc, private-constructor

Having a `AppConfig.java` without annotation-scanning because of security and and without configuration via an `app-config.xml` because of harder-binding, I create instances of spring-beans like this:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
  @Bean
  public AddressService addressService(){
    return new AddressService();
  }
}
```

Everything works great but what if I like to prevent others to create a Instance of `AddressService`? Usually I would declare the constructor private, but the compiler gives me a error that i can not access the private constructor of  `AddressService` in the `AppConfig` anymore!

For completeness, this is the `AddressService`:

```
public final class AddressService {
  private AddressService(){}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a working solution.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    public static class AddressService {
        private AddressService() {}
    }
    @Bean
    public AddressService addressService() {
        return new AddressService();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a public interface and the implementation class package private. Means `AddressingService` is public interface and `AddressingServiceImpl` is just package private with `@Service` annotation. Now nobody will be able to create an instance of your spring-bean and only one instance will be available for others based on your bean scope. You can Autowire the bean as `@Autowired AddressingService`.

A sample junit test case to test if the `AddressingServiceImpl` is used directly in any class within same package.

In this case the classes are in src/main/java/com/address package. and the test class is created in src/test/java/com/address.

```
package com.address;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.*;

public class BeansInitTest {

@Test
public void test() {
    File[] files = new File("src/main/java/com/address").listFiles((File   dir, String name) -> {
        return name.endsWith(".java") &&    !name.equals(AddressServiceImpl.class.getSimpleName() + ".java");
    }
    );

    Arrays.asList(files)
            .stream().forEach(clazz -> checkInstanceCreation(clazz, AddressServiceImpl.class.getSimpleName()));
}

private void checkInstanceCreation(File clazz, String name) {
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(clazz))){

        reader.lines().forEach(l -> {
            Assert.assertFalse(l.contains(name));
        });

    }catch(Exception e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

}

Please note that this is just a sample and can be generalised based on need.

Comment: Why the interface? Why not declaring the constructor package-private?

Comment: Actually, what does it change ? the OP can't (chooses not to) use the annotation-scanning. So he still has to be able to do "new AddressingService", which means the constructor is visible to others too ?

Comment: @Alex The constructor would be visible in the same package, he said `package-private` what is `default` or `protected`.

Comment: I understand, just thought it wasn't restrictive enough (ie not private), but if that is good for you, it's good then ;)

Comment: @Alex Its not good, others can still create their own instance.

Comment: @peter Others can only create instances within  same package only. So a simple junit test case that checks if a new AddressingServiceImpl() is used in same package will help.

Comment: @LyjuIEdwinson If the junittest is that simple, write it into the answer.

Comment: @PeterRader added a sample junit test case in the answer.

Comment: @LyjuIEdwinson The sample only checks my code, not the code of others, this is a security-leak. Another security-leak is that you can skip the junit-tests. Also the package `com.address` may change, i need a development handbook to use this code.

Comment: @PeterRader we don't need to check others code. A default class is only visible in that package. So there is no question of creating an instance of this class anywhere else right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125866/discussion-between-lyju-i-edwinson-and-peter-rader).

Comment: I am not sure why the down vote. It is a solution that works. try it before down voting.

Comment: @LyjuIEdwinson Wrong, the question is about preventing, but a default-package "Allows" something. But the question is about preventing, your answer is about allowing.

Comment: default-package "Allows" something, but the test case prevent that too.